# What happens to an HDC when its window is destroyed?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gdi

I'm writing a library that works with `HWND` and `HDC` under the hood. `ReleaseDC` takes a `HWND` as a parameter, but what if the window has already been destroyed? Does Windows free the `HDC` automatically, or does this cause a resource leak?

Comment: You could try this for yourself. Experiment 1) Repeatedly execute a cycle that creates a window and device contexts, destroys only the window and see if you run out of memory. Experiment 2) the same but call `ReleaseDC` after destroying the window, look at its return value, and see if it causes any problems. Don't be frightened to try things out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219640/what-bad-things-may-happen-without-calling-to-releasedc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When testing on Windows 10, it appears that a DC retrieved with `GetDC` is automatically released when the window is destroyed.

An infinite loop that creates a window, retrieves a DC, and destroys the window had no increase of memory usage after the first iteration. To make sure some internal reference count wasn't being incremented without also being decremented, I changed the loop to repeatedly get a DC from the same window. This not only increased memory usage with each iteration, but also made my entire system slow and unstable.